# Python overwriting file after saving it if command is repeated

Tags: python-2.7

So I've created a program which generates secure pass phrases for websites. I've made it so that if the user would like to save their generated password to a text file they can. Below is the code...

```
if writeyn == 'Y' or 'y' or 'yes' or 'Yes':
        print 'Written to passwords.txt'
        f = open("passwords.txt", "w")
        f.write(passtype + " - " + mypw)
```

It works great, except for one problem. Whenever the user chooses to write their password to a text file the other older entry gets overwritten and replaced with the new one.

For example:

```
$ passgen

$ What service are you using? 'Gmail'

$ Would you like to write your password to a text file? Y or n 'Y'
```

At this point the program would stop and tell you that your password has been written to the passwords.txt file. The program does save the password to the file but if you were to then start up the program again and choose to write your new password to a text file the old one would be overwritten and replaced with the new password. Which is not good. So how do I fix this?

Comment: Use the mode "a" to append. "w" overwrites the old contents.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know this. Thanks!